# Android setNextMediaPlayer() API for MediaPlayer is not playing next video

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have a simple activity which contains one instance of a **VideoView** and a reference to its' **MediaPlayer**. My goal was to use the **setNextMediaPlayer**() api from the **MediaPlayer** object in order to minimize the switching time between 2 videos.

In the below code, the **1st** video plays well. When the **1st** video completes, the **2nd** video's audio begins to play in the background, but only the last frame of the **1st** video is shown.

Do you know what the problem is? Why isn't the **2nd** video's video displaying?

```
private VideoView player1;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1;

public static final String URL_1 = "https://example.com/video1.mp4";
public static final String URL_2 = "https://example.com/video2.mp4";

public static final String TAG = "PrebufferingActivity";

public boolean FIRST_TIME = true;
public int count = 0;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prebuffering);

    player1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer1);

    player1.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)          {
            mediaPlayer1 = mp;

            if(FIRST_TIME == true)
            {
                mediaPlayer1.start();
                player1.requestFocus();
                FIRST_TIME = false;
            }
        }
    });

    player1.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)          
        {
            if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START)
            {
                count++;
                if(count % 2 != 0)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Odd count (" + count + ") Prebuffering URL_2");
                    MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(PrebufferingActivity.this, Uri.parse(URL_2));
                    mp.setNextMediaPlayer(myMediaPlayer);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Even count (" + count + ") Prebuffering URL_1");
                    MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(PrebufferingActivity.this, Uri.parse(URL_1));
                    mp.setNextMediaPlayer(myMediaPlayer);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    player1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        }
    });

    // Player 1
    player1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    player1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URL_1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you create new `MediaPlayer`, but `VideoView` knows nothing about and can't control it. It wouldn't work properly.

If you need some specific functions probably you need to build your analog of `VideoView`, that would use `MediaPlayer`.

Regarding playing 2nd video by using `setNextMediaPlayer()` you can find some hints here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28465846/755313

Comment: Hi demaksee, thanks for your answer. I created a new MediaPlayer and set it as the nextMediaPlayer here: MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(PrebufferingActivity.this, Uri.parse(URL_1));
                    mp.setNextMediaPlayer(myMediaPlayer);     Since "mp" is associated to VideoView, shouldn't this work?

Comment: Shouldn't. VideoView knows only about own MediaPlayer (mp in this case), and method setNextMediaPlayer no effect in this case. If you need you own custom video view, you should write it:
public class CustomVideoView extends View {
   MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
...
}